# What's the difference between jQuery.bind() and jQuery.on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

And why is .on() now preferred in jQuery 1.7?

Comment: [Here](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/) is the blog entry wherein the jQuery team describes `.on()` and `.off()`.

Comment: The summary of it being: "The new .on() and .off() APIs unify all the ways of attaching events to a document in jQuery — and they’re shorter to type!"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`.on()` now offers a combination of `.live()`, `.delegate()` and `.bind()` all in one unified method.  You can get the behavior of any of those three just by how you use the arguments to `.on()`.

These pairs are functionally the same:

```
// events bound directly to the object they occur on
$('.button').on('click', fn);
$('.button').bind('click', fn);

// events intercepted after bubbling up to a common parent object
$('.container').on("click", '.button', fn);
$('.container').delegate('.button', "click", fn);
```

More info is described in a [jQuery blog entry](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/).

Before unifying these separate functions, jQuery had multiple different implementations.  Now, `.on()` is the superset function and `.bind()`, `.live()` and `.delegate()` all just call `.on()` in their implementation so there is now only one implementation of the actual event handling.  So, from that standpoint, it was also a code cleanup and streamlining issue.  Similarly, `.die()`, `.undelegate()` and `.unbind()` just call `.off()` now rather than have separate implementations.

Note: `.live()` has been deprecated for all versions of jQuery because it's just a special case of intercepting all the bubbled events on the document object so it can be easily replaced with either `.delegate()` or `.on()` and when lots of events were all being handled on the document object, it could become a performance problem checking lots of selectors on every event.  It's much more efficient to hook a delegated event like this to a common parent that is much closer to where the event occurs than put them all on the document object (thus why `.live()` is not good to use).

From the jQuery 1.7 source, you can see how all these functions just now call `.on()` and `.off()`:

```
bind: function( types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, null, data, fn );
},
unbind: function( types, fn ) {
    return this.off( types, null, fn );
},

live: function( types, data, fn ) {
    jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
    return this;
},
die: function( types, fn ) {
    jQuery( this.context ).off( types, this.selector || "**", fn );
    return this;
},

delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, selector, data, fn );
},
undelegate: function( selector, types, fn ) {
    // ( namespace ) or ( selector, types [, fn] )
    return arguments.length == 1? this.off( selector, "**" ) : this.off( types, selector, fn );
},
```

Answer (score 3):

The MAIN difference is that .bind requires the element (selector) exist AT THE TIME it gets attached, whereas .on does not have that requirement, and .on frankly has better/more elegant syntax in my opinion.  See the documentation first paragraph http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: In this use of `$(selector).on('click', fn)`,  the selector must still exist at the time it gets attached.   In this version `$(parentselector).on('click', selector, fn)`, the `parentselector` must exist at the time it gets attached, but the other `selector` does not have to exist yet.  It is important to understand what must exist and what can be created later.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification, and always,` $(document).on(`  is available for attachement as your "parentselector" in your example.

Comment: Yes, but using `$(document).on()` for lots of events causes performance issues.  That's why `.live()` has been deprecated because that's what it did.  It's much better to pick a parent selector much closer to the actual event that isn't the same selector used for lots of other types of events.

Comment: @jfriend00 - true, but I did not intend to fully document .bind() .on() and .live() here but merely to point out the major difference between .bind() and .on()

Answer (score 1):

The old method was a bit messy - the difference between `live()`, `delegate()` and `bind()` was not clear. By making `on()` the function that handles attaching any event, regardless of whether it exists or not, it's just easier to work with.

Before now, `live()` was a lot slower than the new `on()` function, hence why you had to choose between `bind()` and `live()`.

Comment: Given the correct parameters that will mimic the functionality of `live`, I think `on` is just as slow.

Comment: I personally haven't profiled it, so can't say, but according to the jQuery post, it is much quicker than the `live()` implementation. Of course, they would say that, but it might be true.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I misread you slightly.  They did say they improved event delegation.