# How to clone an element with data without events with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to clone a `<select>` tag with it's data attribute but without its events.

Following [JQuery Official .clone() api](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), I understand I can clone without data and events by calling
`$('#grolsh').clone()`, or perform a

`$('#grolsh').clone(true)` which will copy data and events.

I want to keep the data but clear the events associates with the original item.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As from version 1.7, [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) is the preferred method for unbinding:

```
$('#grolsh').clone(true).off();
```

Comment: So what is the difference between .off() and .unbind()?

Comment: read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113783/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-bind-and-jquery-on

Answer (score 11):

Just use

`$('#grolsh').clone();` // **Copies the element structure**

`$('#grolsh').clone(true)` // **Copies both data and events along with the structure**

`$('#grolsh').clone(true).off()` // **Copies both data and events and removes handlers**

Events bound with `.on()` and removed using `.off()`;

Events bound with `.bind()` and removed using `.unbind()`;

Comment: first case is not true, data isn't copied with `clone()` and no arguments  http://jsfiddle.net/ALxz4/

Comment: The docs states "As of jQuery 1.4, all element data (attached by the .data() method) is also copied to the new copy." but from my testing, normal clone() didn't copy the data

Answer (score 2):

By adding an **[.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)**:

```
$('#grolsh').clone(true)
    .attr({'id': 'newGrolsh'})
    .off()
    .appendTo('#target');
```

**Updated:**
As Adrian suggested **.off** would be a better solution over **.unbind**

Answer (score 1):

As of from jQuery version 1.5, you can pass second parameter (See: [.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] [, deepWithDataAndEvents ] )](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents))not to copy the event handler:

```
$('#grolsh').clone(true,false);
```

Comment: Nope, that is just "A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all children of the cloned element should be copied. " - it may seem like it if your `#grolsh` does not have any events, just data... but it is not like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to copy data attached by the `.data()` method **don't abuse event (un)binding** and just do:

```
var $original = $(".originalSelector");
var $clone = $original.clone().data( $original.data() );
```

Because when you pass an object to `.data()` method, it extends the current data with it.

**!IMPORTANT NOTE!**

You can't do this if you are going to use something that stores DOM references and uses it e.g. **jQuery UI draggable** etc...

 => only use on "pure" data / basic types