# Clone Append Jquery stops effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

cloned parallax jquery stops working after appending to dom.
Check my example : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYOrEO

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="clone">Clone</a>
</div>
<section class="content">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center bg-faded my-5" style="background: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/abstract/1') no-repeat center;" data-paroller-factor="0.5">
    <h1 class="heading-1 py-5 text-white">Hello Parallax!</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
$(window).paroller();
$(function(){
  $('.clone').on('click', function() {
    alert('hi');
    $(".jumbotron").clone().appendTo(".content");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$('#grolsh').clone(); // Copies the element structure

$('#grolsh').clone(true) // Copies both data and events along with the structure

$('#grolsh').clone(true).off() // Copies both data and events and removes handlers

Events bound with .on() and removed using .off();

Events bound with .bind() and removed using .unbind();
```

//Your updated code may this help

```
$(window).paroller();
$(function(){
  $('.clone').on('click', function() {
    alert('hi');
        $(".jumbotron").clone(true).prependTo(".content");
        $(window).paroller();
  });
});
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142118/how-to-clone-an-element-with-data-without-events-with-jquery)

Comment: this is not working too can you explain me through my added example on link: codepen